# Looking for Search algorithm in both direction - c / c++ / awk

Tags: c++, c, shell, awk

I working on some computation modelling, in which I need to search data which is irregularly spaced and data is not sorted , so here is scenario

My sample data points

```
col1 col2 
1    92
9    45
7    22
2    14
5    10
```

So search algorithm I am looking is like this,

say if `key = 2` then function should return index of `2` since its available, say for example I want to search `3`, its not there in `col1`, since its not available, I need to search nearest value in both direction that is index of `2` and `5`

in case of `awk` exact key can be searched using something like this

```
  function search(Arr,key){
                             if((key in Arr))
                              return key
                          }
```

But I really don't know but to search nearest value in both upper and lower direction, in case of exact key not found

I hope my requirement is clear, in case of negative voting, please put your comment also, since my problem is because of less reputation(new to this forum),  I am unable to vote up for useful answers, please co-operate.

Comment: Did you try sorting the array and then using `Binary Search` as that can give you both upper and lower value.

Comment: Doing it in a shell or in AWK will be hard, unless you read the file as in a C or C++ program. In C it's not too hard, and in C++ it's easy. However, no none will probably give you a complete solution (which will be ***very*** different depending on language used) without you showing some effort to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg :  Thanks for response, I am actually using matlab as it has got many inbuilt function but matlab is very slow.. so I looking for solution in `c / c++ / awk `

Comment: @G one :   Thanks for response can I have one sample example please.. I am not very good programmer..

Comment: Just Google searching(Binary search) and sorting technique(merge, bubble, quick), you'll find lot of examples. Still you don't understand then revert:)

Comment: @Gone why sorting when you can keep things linear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not sorted, the best is to search for the exact, lower and upper at the same time to iterate over the data only once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using Samples = std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>;

Samples::const_iterator Find( Samples const & samp_, int val_, Samples::const_iterator & prev_, Samples::const_iterator & next_ ) {
    auto end = std::end(samp_);
    auto lower = end;
    auto upper = end;
    auto it = begin(samp_);
    for( ; it!=end; ++it) {
        if ( it->first == val_ )
            return it;
        if ( it->first < val_ && ( lower == end || lower->first < it->first ) )
            lower = it;
        else if ( it->first > val_ && ( upper == end || upper->first > it->first ) )
            upper = it;
    }
    prev_ = lower;
    next_ = upper;
    return end;
}

std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, std::pair<int,int> const & p ) {
    return os << "( " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " )";
}

int main() {
    Samples samps { {1,92}, {9,45},{7,22},{2,14},{5,10} };

    auto test = [&] ( int v ) {
        Samples::const_iterator lower;
        Samples::const_iterator upper;
        auto result = Find( samps, v, lower, upper );
        if ( result != end( samps ) ) {
            std::cout << "found " << *result << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "not found ";
            if ( lower  != end( samps ) )
                std::cout << "lower is " << *lower;
            else 
                std::cout << "no lower";
            if ( upper  != end( samps ) )
                std::cout << " upper is " << *upper;
            else 
                std::cout << " no upper";
            std::cout << std::endl; 
        }
    };
    test(2);
    test(3);
    test(12);
    test(-1);
}
```

And the result :

```
found ( 2, 14 ) 
not found lower is ( 2, 14 ) upper is ( 5, 10 ) 
not found lower is ( 9, 45 ) no upper
not found no lower upper is ( 1, 92 )
```

Comment: You are really top class programmer, I really don't know how many weeks/months I take to convert your c++ code to c. can you please put comment in your code ? so that it will be easy for me to convert it to c

Comment: just replace iterators and the autos with int indices, begin is 0, end is -1, the vector of pair is a C array of a struct pair with the tko members, `pair samps[N];` and you iterate over the array with indices from 0 to size.

Comment: How did you compile ? my getting error msg I tried `g++ search.cpp` on terminal

Comment: Need '-std=c++11' option

Comment: $ g++ -std=c++11 search.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’

Answer (score 3):

Shell solution,

```
perl -lane'
BEGIN{ $k=pop }
push @r, [@F];
END { 
  for (sort{ $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @r) {
    $v= $_->[0] <=> $k;
    $h{$v} = $_->[1];
    last if $v >0;    
  }
  print join " ", ($h{0} or @h{-1,1});
}
' file 3
```

output

```
14 10
```

Answer (score 2):

In Gnu Awk version 4, you could use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` like:

```
gawk -vkey=7 -f a.awk file
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
{
    a[$1]=$2
}
END {
    if (key in a)
        print "Found key "key" with value "a[key]
    else {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"
        for (i in a) {
            if (i+0>key) { k=i; break}
            j=i
        }
        if (j)  
            print "Prev key: "j
        if(k)
            print "Next key: "k
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$gawk -vkey=6 -f a.awk file

Prev key: 5
Next key: 7

$gawk -vkey=5 -f a.awk file

Found key 5 with value 10
```